# BigQuery Python cannot delete dataset: Dataset is still in use

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am writing an integration test using the `google-cloud-bigquery` python library.

My test follows these steps:

- Create new dataset
- Create table in dataset
- Insert rows into table
- Do some stuff, make sure the stuff makes sense
- Delete the dataset

However, when I try and delete the dataset I get the error `google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 DELETE {url}: Dataset {dataset} is still in use`

Looking at the BigQuery UI I see `This table has records in the streaming buffer that may not be visible in the preview.`

Clearly, BigQuery needs to finish doing its thing before I can delete.

Is there a sane way of blocking until I am able to delete the dataset?

Comment: delete this table first and then delete dataset

Answer (score -2):

Do a function like this

```
Def closedataset():
    Close the dataset

Def deletedataset():
    Delete the dataset

Dostuff()
closedataset()
Deletedataset()
```

This may or may not work. I don’t have your code